# autohotkey keyboard remapping

Tags: autohotkey

i have problems with my laptop keyboard output (tried with usb keyboard everything works perfectly, bought new one-still same problem,reinstalled drivers,windows,registry entries looks correct,even in bios keyboard have same problem,keyboard connector cleard and looks fine) .. so every time i press key 'v' it comes out as 'v6' and when i press '6' comes out as 'v6', when i press 'b' it comes out as 'b8' and when press '8' it comes out as 'b8' and so on with several others keys..

1. if someone knows what is the problem with my laptop or know solution pls let me know,
2. i would like to write script in autohotkey but i dont know how to write correct command line for my problem..so this is what i want to acommplish: clearly when i press v i want v not v6 :p .. so i want command line that will erase with backspace this faulty 6..
   when i enter command line 'v::backspace' it comes out '6' and i want 'v'. When i write '6::backspace' it doesnt comes out nothing so im confused and need correct command line or some kind of solution (except changing motherboard,and im sure it would solve the problem).

tnx!!

Comment: Wow! before I (and others) can try to help you, just a few questions. 1. Does the behaviour you describe happen WITHOUT AutoHotKey running? 2. What is the brand/type of your laptop? 3. What are the keyboard LAYOUT and LANGUAGE settings? 4. What does the physical keyboard layout look like. 5. What operating system are you using (e.g. Win7) and what is the OS user language (e.g. English, German, French...)? You said "bought a new one"! A new laptop? a new built-in keyboard? or a new external USB keyboard? Oh b.t.w. I think that this is not an AutoHotKey question but much more HW troubleshooting.

Comment: I think that anyone who really wants to help me understand my problem w/o answers to your questions and to help me around autohotkey they need to know root of my problem

Comment: as u r only one here with good will ill answer on all.

Comment: 1.sure the problem is present w/o autohotkey

Comment: 2. Acer Aspire 7730G 3. language and layout is Croatian 4. not sure what exactly u want here 5. win 7 english 6. i tried with new built in keyboard, with usb external keyborad all keys works perfect

Comment: OK, I assume that you use an international keyboard layout (qwerty) and the keyboard input language is set to Croation. What happens when you set the input language to English in [control panel], [region & language]? do you still get "v6" and "b8" instead of "v" or "b"? I would also look in this thread:  http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-97177-urgent-my-keyboard-types-numbers-and-letters

Comment: i changed now input language to english and it is still v6 :/ .. man tnx for trying.. If you've got a more suggestions pls tell me .. tnx

Comment: i tried all suggested combos from that link and nothing .. i have on f12 scr lk and with fn deos not have any function and i hoped the problem is in that :/

Comment: I can't think of any root cause other than a the keyboard interface chip on the motherboard causes this. What does the AutoHotKey key history show when you press such a "double" key. Right-click on the AHK icon, then select [Open], [View], [Key History and script info]. I wonder if this will show one keypress or two. I.e. is the I/O chip OK and is the problem somewhere else?

Comment: on one press on 'v' ahk key history shows this : 56  02F   d 22.12 V               
36  007   d 0.00 6               
56  02F   u 0.13 V               
36  007   u 0.01 6

Comment: d 22.12 V               
d 0.00 6               
u 0.13 V               
u 0.01 6 simplyfied..so it is two presses i assume

Comment: is this kayborad interface chip changeable ?

Comment: First question. do you get double char's on ALL key or just a few? Looking at the elapse time it looks like there is a shortcut between two wires since both key down and up are executed immediately after each other. Check the flat ribbon cable and make sure it fits precisely. Also check the connector and the soldering points of the connector for any shortcut problems. I'd like to find the root cause, but if all else fails, you could write a script to "catch" those pesky double key presses and turn them into "regular" key presses.

Comment: no double chars r only on 8 keys, i checked that connector more then one time and it looks fine w/o any damage and strange color and with new build in keyboard is the same problem so it cant be in that flat ribbon cable. ill disassemble today whole laptop so i can check that soldering points or any visible shortcut problem.

Comment: i would be really greatfull if u could write me this script just for one key or at least to point me in right direction or some kind tutorial..rly thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, just replace the v6 or b8 like this:

```
:?*:v6::v
:?*:b8::b
```

Comment: yea great..that is just a half way there coz when i hit key 6 or v it comes out v6 and with that line my 6 is now v too :/

Comment: This a strong indication that there is indeed a shortcut between two signal lines as discussed before. When you monitor the key history in AutoHotKey, is there a difference between hitting v or hitting 6 (sequence/timing, etc)?

Comment: B.t.w. this problem will likely also affect shortcuts like [Cntrl]+v (Paste) or [Shift]+v, thus making the list of "corrections" inside AutoHotKey larger and dramatically reduce the options for "alternatives" to access e.g. the 6 above the letters T and Y (numpad 6 should work differently) and ^ (above the 6). In that case, you would probably have to use [Alt]+6 for 6 and [Shift]+[Alt]+6 for ^....

Comment: those extra letters is allways 0.01s or 0.02s after first on all foulty keys.

Comment: i should definitely look under board for those shortcut..btw with yours command lines in ahk all mine letter keys now works like there is not any problem with it..lucky i have num keys for numbers..

Comment: and im not sure is this mean something but yesterday i installed 'sharpkeys' prg for remapping keyboard in registry and this program recognise those foulty keys (v,b,6,1..) with some strange hex number..all functional keys have hex numer like 00_1F or 00_2D and and e.g. mine v key have E0_3F2F and b have E0_3F30 .. is this telling u anything more ? tnx

Comment: Good work, I heard of sharpkeys and once used it, but I would have to start investigate this my self as well. At least this shows that it is not simply two keys being hit at (almost) the same time. If sharpkeys can differentiate between v and 6 or b and 8 then your'e golden! An other alternative you can look into is HIDMacros.

Comment: i cant assign any key to this faulty ones in sharpkey coz sharpkey cant recognise those except he can tell me this strange hex for faulty keys :/

Comment: and i wanna to say thanks one more time u helped me a lot! :)

Comment: ..i need to set up key 'e' to do two things..first hit 'y' key and hold it and second thing while still holding 'y' to hit on 'x'.. is this possible to write in ahk ?i hope u undestood me and rly sorry for bad english..tnx again

Comment: This should work:   e::Send {y down}x{y up} (all in one line)
or if you need more time between the keystrokes: (multiple lines after e::)
e::
Send {y down}
Sleep, 50
Send x
Sleep, 50
Send {y up}
Return